# Error = Cannot resolve symbol GoogleCloudMessaging in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-intentservice

I am using android studio 1.2.1 and working on push notification service using GCM  error is given in 
intentservice

> "Cannot Resolve GoogleCloudMessaging"

Here is code:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
Log.e("test recieve", "-----Catch");
if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
    if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
            .equals(messageType)) {
        sendNotification("Send error"+ extras.toString());
    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
            .equals(messageType)) {
        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                + extras.toString());
    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
            .equals(messageType)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Log.i(TAG,
                    "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                            + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        sendNotification(""+extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
        Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
    }
}
GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

** this is my Build Gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
       android
       {
   compileSdkVersion 22
   buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
   defaultConfig
        {
     applicationId "insidesoftwares.gcmpush"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 22
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes
        {
        release
            {
          minifyEnabled false
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
   }
  dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
  compile project(path:':backend',configuration: 'android-endpoints')
  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
  compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
   }
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: have you added google play services library in your project?

Comment: yes added google play service jar in library

Comment: please post your build.gradle file

Comment: try compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'

Comment: did you added gcm.jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try adding this in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0'
```

OR

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on gcm recently and had no problem. Used [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) method. Only one that i got was even after getting registration token the gcm api was giving not registered message. Its solution was to uninstall your app from the device and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

in your `Build.gradle` file.